# Setup Golden Gate on Oracle Linux 7.4, with Oracle version 12.2.0.1

Tags: oracle, oraclelinux

I am trying to setup Golden Gate on Oracle Linux 7.4, with Oracle version 12.2.0.1.

The Oracle OTN (To Download) does not list the Golden Gate version for Oracle Linux for 12.2.0.1, is it not supported or which version should I use.

OTN Link:
https://www.oracle.com/in/middleware/technologies/goldengate-downloads.html

Comment: Oracle changed version numbers that corresponds with the year of release.You can download latest version i,e `Oracle GoldenGate 19.1.0.0.4 for Oracle on Linux x86-64`and when you run set up  it gives options for 4 database versions viz 11g,12c,18c and 19c

Comment: Ohk, I got the 12c version downloaded from https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SoftwareDelivery

Comment: Will try this also thanks for the answer.